# How to customize DataGrid in WinUI3 via C#

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a DataGrid table (from CommunityToolkit.Controls), created by C# code (creating via XAML doesn't work for me).

```
DataGrid table = new DataGrid();
table.ColumnWidth = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
table.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
table.ItemsSource = doubleColumnTable;
table.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.All;
table.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
```

How to change row height, border color, font weight and size via C#? I found just few examples of style changing in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid table = new DataGrid();
    table.ColumnWidth = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
    table.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    table.ItemsSource = Items;
    table.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.All;
    table.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;

    this.Resources["GridLinesBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);

    Content = table;

    // Update font size.
    table.DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (s is not DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (DataGridTextColumn column in dataGrid.Columns.OfType<DataGridTextColumn>())
        {
            column.FontSize = 30;
         }
    };

    // Update row height.
    table.LoadingRow += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Row.Height = 50;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It working. But How to change font size in table body?

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: OK, thank you. Is it possible to somehow make Setter to Gridview style via C#?

Comment: It might be possible. Can you post it as a new question? It's not recommended to extend questions, especially when they are not related to the original one. ;)